# not showing the label information completely on the chart when there is no enough space show full text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am working on angularjs google chart API timeline chart.
Please find the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/Krrz1uCeNlvl849E1P1x?p=preview

I am showing multiple rows information in a single row as shown in the demo. 
 when there are multiple rows information shown in a single row as shown in the demo plunker above, it is not showing the label information on the chart When there is no enough place to show the label. The text "first row label" is not shown on the chart because there is no enough space to display it, similarly in row2 also labels are not shown on the chart. Is there a way that **if the place is not enough to show the label on the chart i need to move the row2 information to the second row in the chart**?

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope,$timeout) {
        var chart1 = {};
        chart1.type = "Timeline";
        chart1.displayed = false;
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline')
        chart1.data = {
            "cols": [{
                id: "month",
                label: "Month",
                type: "string"
            }, {
                id: "laptop-id",
                label: "Laptop",
                type: "string"
            }, {
                id: "desktop-id",
                label: "start",
                type: "date"
            }, {
                id: "server-id",
                label: "end",
                type: "date"
            }],
            "rows": [{
                c: [{
                    v: "Jan"
                }, {
                    v: "first row label",
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 3, 1)
                }, {
                    v:new Date(2018, 3, 1)
                } ]
            }, {
                c: [{
                    v: "Jan"
                }, {
                    v: "second row label"
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,3, 15)
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 4, 15)
                } ]
            } , {
                c: [{
                    v: "feb"
                }, {
                    v: "Beginning JavaScript text for feb"
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,5, 5)
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,5, 15)
                } ]
            } , {
                c: [{
                    v: "feb"
                }, {
                    v: "Beginning JavaScript"
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 6, 15)
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 6, 17)
                } ]
            } , {
                c: [{
                    v: "feb"
                }, {
                    v: "Beginning JavaScript some text here"
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018,6, 1)
                }, {
                    v: new Date(2018, 6, 2)
                } ]
            }  ]
        };
        chart1.options = {
            timeline: {
                showRowLabels: false,
            },
        };

        $scope.myChart = chart1;

    });
```

PS: I know that tooltip option is available, but i want to show the labels displayed on the chart instead of showing in the tooltip.

Comment: Any inputs on this post?

Comment: looks the issue is related to html and css. can u pls create a plnkr for this?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure - I have kept the plunker link in the post above..https://plnkr.co/edit/Krrz1uCeNlvl849E1P1x?p=preview . In the plunker demo, we can notice that in the first row we displayed two rows information and due to lack of space the first row label information is not shown on the chart. Same in the second row also we displayed 3 rows information(orange,violet,green) and it is not showing the label info for 2nd and 3rd row data. When this situation occur i want the row to move down so that it displays the labels.

Comment: you'll have to compare the `<text>` elements produced by the chart, with the labels in the data table, to find the missing rows (on the `'ready'` event) -- then modify the rows accordingly, and re-draw the chart...

Comment: @WhiteHat - Label names are not shown on the chart when there is no enough place to show the label text.In my demo https://plnkr.co/edit/Krrz1uCeNlvl849E1P1x?p=preview .we can notice when two rows are side by side and there is no enough place to show the label text the label is not shown  on the chart. So when there is no enough place to show the label, i want to show the row in the next line..

Comment: i understand, which is why you will have to inspect the chart after it draws, to determine which labels are not displayed, then fix the data and draw again -- there aren't any config options for this...

Comment: @WhiteHat - As suggested i tried to mange the row information , but could not get the value. Can you please guide . I tried searching some examples but could not find one. Please find my updated demo https://plnkr.co/edit/xogetreVSLL2uiYVxmhM?p=preview . In the demo we can notice in first row third row label is not shown on the chart due to lack of space.When such occurs i want to show that row information in next line so that label can be seen. Please advice.Thanks a much.

Comment: Any inputs would be of great help..